# What is the better way to implement video files playback in application background?

Tags: ios, video, appstore-approval

I do need to implement iOS application with video files played back in background.

E.g. on first viewController one video should be played back in background instead of some photo or color background.
on second viewController another video should be played back in background instead of some photo or color background.
and so on.

What is the best way to implement this?
* is it better to import those video files in project?
* or is it better to store them in some external place and playback via network?

From the AppStore approval point of view and from the Apple Guidlines point of view - is this case with video correct? Or it's better to avoid video usage in mobile applications?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is definitely very vague. Without know specifics of your videos (duration, size, bitrate...), how many you have, if you have specific versions for different devices (e.g. iPhone/iPad), and what their purpose really is, it would be difficult to provide a valid answer. There are a few rules about videos in the App Store Review Guidelines, I'm sure you'll have found them.

Comment: One good way to know which is the right way is to think about what you would think if you were the one using the app, both in the case were you have Wi-Fi, and in the case when you are on a cellular network...

Comment: "Better to store locally vs play from network" is a separate question depending on multiple factors: file size, available on-device storage,  how/where your users would be watching, etc. Are they at home using a 64GB iPad on Wi-Fi? Or traveling in remote areas with a 2G connection and a 16GB iPhone 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution with local video files playback via native `AVPlayer` from `AVFoundation`

1.Import AVFoundation:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

2.Use property for player:

```
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
```

3.Add video file into "Video" folder and added "Video" into project

4.Initialize the player

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shutterstock_v885172.mp4" ofType:nil inDirectory:@"Video"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
videoLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];

[self.avPlayer play];
```

5.Subscribe for event - video did play to the end

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];
```

6.Resume video playback to the very start in related method

```
- (void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification {
    AVPlayerItem *player = [notification object];
    [player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```